# HTML button funtion doesnt work properlty

Tags: javascript, html, button

when I put a button inside the div id="box" then the button appears as a tiny rectangular box, whereas when i put it outside the div id="box" then it appears correctly with the proper text contained within it.

Please take a look on this link:

```css
<style>#box {
  border: yellow 5px solid;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

#box img {
  width:
}

#box button {
  /* adjust the button width to fit nicely */
  width: 10px;
  ;
  height: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="task1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
  <h1> Owais Ughratdar </h1>
  <div id="box">
    <img id="light" src="light_0.jpg">
    <div>
      <button> ON </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: You made your button be 4px high and 10px wide and you're confused why it looks like a little box ?

Comment: If it's outside the box, the `#box button` CSS doesn't apply to it.

Comment: ...you deliberately set the button to be 10x4 pixels. It's right there in your CSS.

Comment: When you put it inside of the div "box" you are also applying some css rules. When it's not inside the div the rules don't apply, it's obviously a css issue.

Comment: Thanks GUYS!! I'll change the dimensions. I'm a beginner :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS file, try experimenting with  `#box button`...need to make `width` and `height` much bigger like so:

```
#box button {
      /* adjust the button width to fit nicely */
      width: 300px;;
      height: 200px;
     padding: 2px;
     }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/noLqau4x/

Comment: Thanks for your help, and to everyone who helped!